# iOS B2B program: can you "buy" the app with the same business you developed from?

Tags: ios, b2b

Can a business with an Apple developer account distribute an app that is only purchasable by a VPP account with the same DUNS number?

I'm looking to develop an app for a particular client, and it needs to be able to be manageable for a few years. I don't want to do an AdHoc build as we will not be able to re-distribute the app every year when the provisioning profile expires. So my question is: can I buy a few licenses for my app and distribute the codes to the client to determine what devices they install the app on? I've heard mention that you cannot buy an app with the same company you distributed it from, but I can't find ANYTHING specific in Apple's specifications for it. I also don't want to make the client sign up for VPP, as they don't have a firm company or DUNS number (it is a prototype).

Answer (score 1):

Spent an hour on the phone with Apple Developer support and the answer is NO- you cannot have a VPP with company X buy a B2B app from a developer for company X.